# Percentage of items higher than a specific value ($500) for example?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with items which contains price, item number and personalisation number (which is not needed in this case I think).

How can I make a Query that shows how much percent of the data is >500$ (example.)

I've tried this

```
Select  price, (Count(price)* 100 / (Select Count(*) From items)) as Score
From items
Group By price
```

but it did not work the way I intend it to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Select sum(case when price > 500 then 1 else 0 end) * 100.0 / count(*)
From items
```

Comment: Is there a way I can display the '%' as well? Now it shows 50.00000000 but I'd prefer 50.00%

Comment: Sure, but that should be done in your program Logic. And how you do it (directly in SQL) depends on the DB engine you use. SQL has many different dialects.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17

Comment: To get the right numbers use `cast(sum(case when price > 500 then 1 else 0 end) * 100.0 / count(*) as decimal(5,2))`

Comment: You could add a `convert(varchar, ...) + ' %'` but I would not do that in SQL. SQL is for grabbing data and not for styling it.